# Apprpriate usage of whenever sqlerror

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Correct usage of whenever sqlerror in oracle.
Can we have examples.

Comment: I have voted to close this request, because I have absolutely no idea what you are asking. There is no variable or function called sqlerror in Oracle. So, are you talking of SQL errors in general? But how would you "use" an error? You'd look at the error message, understand it and then fix the error. It is completely unclear what you are asking. Please edit your request and describe clearly what you want to know from us.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it's sqlplus/sqlcl, this controls if a script continues or exists after errror. It's very handy :)

Comment: @Koen Lostrie: Thanks for clarifying. I've removed my close vote, added the sqlplus tag and upvoted your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/WHENEVER-SQLERROR.html#GUID-66C1C12C-5E95-4440-A37B-7CCE7E33491C) says: *Performs the specified action (exits SQL*Plus by default) if a SQL command or PL/SQL block generates an error.*

Nothing easier than an example:

**script without WHENEVER clause**

Create a script (script1.sql) with the following lines. Note the error in the `CREATE TABLE` statement for tab1 - this statement will error out.

```
koens macbook % cat script1.sql
prompt first statement

CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NUMBERX);

prompt second statement

CREATE TABLE tab2 (col2 NUMBER);
```

Now run this script - I'm using sqlcl as client:

```
18c>@script1
first statement

Error starting at line : 3 File @ /Users/klostrie/tmp/script1.sql
In command -
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NUMBERX)
Error report -
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
second statement

Table TAB2 created.

18c>
```

Note that the first statement fails as expected *but the script continues with the next statement*

**script with WHENEVER clause**

Now lets try the same using `WHENEVER SQLERROR`

```
18c>!cat script2.sql
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
prompt first statement

CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NUMBERX);

prompt second statement

CREATE TABLE tab2 (col2 NUMBER);

18c>@script2
first statement

Error starting at line : 4 File @ /Users/klostrie/tmp/script2.sql
In command -
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NUMBERX)
Error report -
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c EE High Perf Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.7.0.0.0
koens macbook %
```

See the difference ? Because of the `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT` the script stops after the first error and exits the oracle client (sqlcl) with the actual error code (ORA-902)

Check the docs for other arguments of WHENEVER SQLERROR.